# Django React axios post request: how to get csrftoken cookie?

Tags: python, django, reactjs, csrf, axios

I am using Django rest framework as my backend (api), and React for the frontend.

Now I want to POST form data to the backend. I want to use `csrf` protection, because of safety. So I am trying to manually set the `csrf` header for my `axios` request using the `csrftoken` cookie send by Django.

[For this I am using the method as recommended in the Django documentation: Link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/csrf/#ajax)

The problem that I am walking into is that I need the cookie on my machine before I can add it to the header, and I don't know how to get the cookie to be returned by Django.

**Main question: how do I get the `csrftoken` cookie on my machine? (While React is rendering the form without (initially) needing any communication with the Django backend)**

Also, if you see any problems with my code, I'd like to know that.

## My code

Here is my current code, and I'll describe the things I have tried:

**django views.py:**

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import ensure_csrf_cookie


@ensure_csrf_cookie
def contact(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        print(request.data)
    if request.method == "GET":
        return request
```

Initially, I only had the POST part of the above function. But since I seem to have no `csrftoken` cookie being send to me by Django I tried to add functionality to the view to get that cookie, using GET. (I have also tried returning an HttpResponse(""), with no effect).

**How do I know I don't have a cookie?**
I am using Chrome, going to the settings > advanced > content settings > cookies > see all cookies and site data

Here i check in "127.0.0.1", since React is running at "127.0.0.1:3000" (and Django at "127.0.0.1:8000").

Initially, I did see a cookie named 'csrftoken', looked like the one I need. Even though my code did not work, I could not POST the data to the backend. I then deleted the cookie, and since then I am not able to get it back.

Added later:
I also checked to see if I see a cookie using the Chrome dev tool (under application > cookies).

**my axios requests:**

```
var axios = require('axios')
var jQuery = require('jquery')


module.exports = {
  ...
  submitForm: function(bodyFormData) {
    console.log("api.submitForm executes")
    axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/customer/contact/',
      data: bodyFormData,
      config: { headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }},
      headers: {"X-CSRFToken": this.getCookieValue('csrftoken')}
    })
      .then(function(response) {
        console.log('response success, response + data:')
        console.log(response)
        console.log(response.data)
        return response.data
      })
      .catch(function(response) {
        console.log('response error, response + data:')
        console.log(response)
        console.log(response.data)
      })
  },

  getCookieValue: function(name) {
    this.getCSRFCookie()
    let cookieValue = null
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
      let cookies = document.cookie.split(";")
      for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        let cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i])
        if (cookie.substring(name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
          cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1))
          break
        }
      }
    }
    console.log("cookieValue: " + cookieValue)
    return cookieValue
  },

  getCSRFCookie: function() {
    console.log("getCSRFCookie")
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/customer/contact/')
  }
}
```

While looking at the above code, I see that there's probably going to be a problem, even if the cookie is send. I can imagine the request for getting the cookie will not yet be finished, while the POST request for form data to the backend is being executed.

Maybe I can work around that by performing the request for getting the cookie on the loading of the form, instead of while it is being sent. But my main concern now is having access to the cookie in the first place.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am having the same issue. I can see that you have being waiting seven months for an answer, not very prmising

Answer (score 0):

The npm package `django-react-csrftoken` might help you. Use it as a component in your form.

```
import React from 'react';
import DjangoCSRFToken from 'django-react-csrftoken'

class MyLoginForm extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <div className="container">
          <form>
            <DjangoCSRFToken/>
            // xyz
            // submit button
          </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Decorate your corresponding django view with `ensure_csrf_cookie` as mentioned [here](https://github.com/iMerica/django-react-csrftoken#user-content-csrf-cookie-and-react).